# Access Wordpress by Sql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ftp

My Wordpress webpage is installed in Wordpress servers, and I do not know the credentials to access it's SQL database. I have read several approaches such as getting the wp-config.php content where I will find the database name and credentials, so that later I can manage the database with tools such as PhpMyAdmin. This file I have seen in several solutions that is accessed via FTP, but then I find that I do not have the FTP credentials to access my webpage.

The credentials I am entering are:
server: mywebpage.wordpress.com
user: mymail@mailprovider.com
password: my Wordpress password

I know this is a quite typical Wordpress question, but neither of the typical solutions for this problem worked for me. Any guesses?

Comment: I would start by looking at the database in cPanel, where you would likely see the user/password.  If not, then you can try PhpMyAdmin with the following command to get user-names and (encrypted) passwords:  `select User, Host, Password from mysql.user;`

Comment: AFAIR, wordpress.com provides Software-as-a-Service, not a hosting provider. They won't give you direct access to the database or files. You only get what you pay for. If you want a wordpress installation with direct access to the database, order a hosting and install wordpress manually.